# Palindrome check throws infinite loop (using iterator and linked lists collection)

Tags: collections, linked-list, iterator, stack, infinite-loop

I´m trying to write a method to determine if a singly linked list of type string is a palindrome.

The idea is to copy the second half to a stack, then use an iterator to pop the elements of the stack and check that they are the same as the elements from 0 to around half of the singly linked list.

But my iterator method is throwing an infinite loop:

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(LinkedList<String> list, Stack<String> stack ) {
    int halfList = (int) Math.ceil(list.size()/2);   // we get half the list size, then round up in case it´s odd
    // testing: System.out.println("half of size is " + halfList);`
    
    // copy elements of SLL into the stack (push them in) after reaching the midpoint
    int count = 0;
    boolean isIt = true;
    
    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();  
    Iterator<String> itr2 = list.iterator();  
    
    System.out.println("\n i print too! ");
    
    // CHECK!! Node head = list.element();
    
    // LOOP: traverse through SLL and add the second half to the stack (push)
    // if even # of elements
    if ( list.size() % 1 == 0 ) {
        System.out.println("\n me too! ");
        while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
            String currentString = itr.next();      // this throws an exception in thread empty stack exception
            count ++;
            if ( count == halfList ) stack.push(list.element());
            // THIS IS THE INFINITE LOOP
            System.out.println("\n me three! ");
        }
    }
    
    // else, if odd # of elements
    else {
        while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
            count ++;
            if ( count == halfList -1 ) stack.push(list.element());
        }
    }
    
    // Now we compare the first half of the SLL to the stack (pop off elements)
    // even
    if ( list.size() % 1 == 0 ) {       
        while ( itr2.hasNext() ) {
            count ++;
            if ( count == halfList +1 ) break;
            int compared = stack.pop().compareTo(list.element());
            if ( compared != 0) isIt = false;     // if when comparing the two elements, they aren´t similar, palindrome is false
        }
    }   
    // odd
    else {
        while ( itr2.hasNext() ) {
            count ++;
            if ( count == halfList ) break;
            int compared = stack.pop().compareTo(list.element());
            if ( compared != 0) isIt = false;
        }
    }

    return isIt;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues:

- `list.size() % 1 == 0` is not checking whether the size is even. The correct check is `% 2`.
- The stack exception cannot occur on the line where you put that comment. It occurs further down the code where you have `stack.pop()`. The reason for this exception is that you try to pop an element from a stack that has no more elements.
- The infinite loop does not occur where you put that comment. It *would* occur in any of the other loops that you have further in the code: there you never call `itr.next()` or `itr2.next()`, and so you'll loop infinitely if you ever get there.
- The stack never gets more than 1 value pushed unto it. This is because you have a strict equality condition that is only true once during the iteration. This is not what you want: you want half of the list to end up on the stack. This is also the reason why you get a stack error: the second half of your code expects there to be enough items on the stack.
- `push(list.element())` is always going to push the *first* list value to the stack, not the currently iterated one. This should be `push(currentString)`.
- `count ++;` is placed at an unintuitive place in your loops. It makes more sense if that line is moved to become the last statement in the loop.
- The `if ( count` statements are all wrong. If you move `count ++` to be the last statement, then this `if` should read `if ( count >= halfList )` for the even case, and `if ( count > halfList )` for the odd case. Of course, it would have been easier if `halfList` would have been adapted, so that you can deal equally with the odd and even case.
- The second part of your code has not reset the counter, but continues with `count ++`. This will make that `if ( count == halfList )` is never true, and so this is another reason why the `stack.pop()` will eventually raise an exception. Either you should reset the counter before you start that second half (with `count = 0;`) or, better, you should just check whether the stack is empty and then exit the loop.
- The second half of your code does not need to make the distinction between odd or even.
- Instead of setting `isIt` to false, it is better to just immediately exit the *function* with `return false`, as there is no further benefit to keep on iterating.
- The function should not take the stack as an argument: you always want to start with an empty stack, so this should be a local variable, not a parameter.
- There is no use in doing `Math.ceil` on a result that is already an `int`. Division results in an `int` when both arguments are `int`. So to round upwards, add 1 to it before dividing: `(list.size()+1) / 2`
- Avoid code repetition

Most of these problems are evident when you debug your code. It is not so helpful to put print-lines with "I am here". Beter is to print values of your variables, or to step through your code with a good debugger, while inspecting your variables. If you had done that, you would have spotted yourself many of the issues listed above.

Here is a version of your code where the above issues have been resolved:

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(LinkedList<String> list) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(); 
    int halfList = (list.size()+1) / 2; // round upwards
    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator(); 
    
    while (halfList-- > 0) itr.next(); // skip first half of list
    while ( itr.hasNext() ) stack.push(itr.next()); // flush rest unto stack

    Iterator<String> itr2 = list.iterator();  
    while ( itr2.hasNext() && !stack.empty()) { // check that stack is not empty
        if (stack.pop().compareTo(itr2.next()) != 0) return false; // no need to continue
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?

Comment: hi @trincot, apologies for the delay! This was 100% correct and very helpful, thank you!

Comment: any chance you could please expand on the while (halfList-- >0) ?

Comment: Yes, that may look more cryptic than it is. The `--` decrements the `halfList` value, and `>0` checks whether it was still nonzero *before* that decrement was done. So it just means that that `while` loop iterates exactly `halfList` times, bringing that variable to 0 as a side-effect.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, that makes sense.